# Push deleted items into temporary table after MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, merge

A simple query on the INTO clause. When i try the below statement, the items get pushed into CustomersBackup2013 whether the table exists or not.

```
SELECT *
INTO CustomersBackup2013
FROM Customers;
```

However, when i try using the into clause in a MERGE like

```
MERGE TargetTable tt
USING SyncTable st on <condition>
.
.
WHEN Not MATCHED BY SOURCE
DELETE
OUTPUT deleted.* INTO #Sometemptable;
```

I get an error saying invalid object name '#Sometemptable'

Isnt it supposed to create the table if it does not exist? Is there something I am doing wrong.

Is there any way i can modify the clause to push items into #Sometemptable?

Answer (score 1):

No, the table has to exists for the `output` clause to work.

First create the #temp table and then you can output deleted values in it. Columns in the temp table must match columns from output by ordinal and type.

Comment: I somehow need to record the items in deleted into #Sometemptable. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

`select into table` creates a table if required. it is much like oracle's `create table as select`. see here [select into table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)

`merge` only inserts, updates or deletes